# Why is the floating element pushed outside of the container when there's no more space on the line instead of being pushed into the second line?

Tags: html, css

```css
blockquote {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 410px;
  height: 400px;
}

blockquote p {
  float: ;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

blockquote img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <img src="https://socialbrew.dk/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/171026-better-coffee-boost-se-329p_67dfb6820f7d3898b5486975903c2e51.fit-760w-1.jpg">
  <p>I love to drink Coffee</p>
  <p>Cofee is the nectar of life</p>
</blockquote>
```

In this example, the two `p` are not floating. They are now `inline-block`, and their normal doc. flow is to be aligned next to the `img`, but not at the top of the container, but at the bottom of the container. Now, if I shrink the `width` of the container to `400px`, the second `p` will be pushed down to the second line, which starts from left and is beneath the image. So the second `p` gets arranged beneath the image on the second line.

If, however, I don't shrink the `width`, and instead, I float the two `p`, they will both get elevated to the top right corner of the container, and now, if i shrink the width of the container again to `400px`, the second `p` appears to be pushed outside of the container, instead of getting pushed down to the second line, however, is it not possible that, when both "p" are floating at the top, their actual order position in the **DOM** is at the bottom of the container, so once the container is smaller, the second `p` is pushed below to the second line, which is beneath the image and exceeding the container, and since it's floating, it gets elevated to the right of the container.

The only issue with this is that, I'm not sure and don't know if that is how floating works. When both `p` are floating at the top right corner of the container, is their actual **DOM** flow order at the bottom of the container, and just giving the false impression that the entire container is empty, or is their order at the top of the container where they actually appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time you didn't set the `width` of `p` it automatically determined by the contents or text inside it and if you reduce the `width` of the container to `400px` and reduce the text inside the `p` will continue to align inline the following is example

```css
blockquote {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

blockquote p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: ;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

blockquote img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <img src="https://socialbrew.dk/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/171026-better-coffee-boost-se-329p_67dfb6820f7d3898b5486975903c2e51.fit-760w-1.jpg">
  <p>I love to drink Coffee</p>
  <p>Cofee is the nectar</p>
</blockquote>
```

as you can see the `p` remains on the same line though I set the `width` its container to `400px` means that in your example the size of two `p` are more than the left size of width of the container.

Try to use developer tool(`ctrl + shift + I` if you're on chrome) in you browser to detect the style here is photo of the width of `p` even thought you didn't set it[image: width of second p]
as you can see the width of second `p` is `162.156px` but you didn't set it means it is actually determined by the length of text.

The second which you were asking about an elevation of two `p` is because when you float content automatically it goes to the side you float it at the top and if you didn't float it it will leave the size which is equal to the height of `img` from the `top` but if you set the height of `img` to `0px` the `p` will go to the top the following is example

```css
blockquote {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 410px;
  height: 400px;
}

blockquote p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: ;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

blockquote img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <img src="https://socialbrew.dk/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/171026-better-coffee-boost-se-329p_67dfb6820f7d3898b5486975903c2e51.fit-760w-1.jpg">
  <p>I love to drink Coffee</p>
  <p>Cofee is the nectar of life</p>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help me, but there is a huge gap between what i am trying to tell you, and what you think i am trying to tell you. There is a big misunderstanding. You keep trying to prove to me something that i am not asking. I know that the two "p" have larger width than the container, but my question was that, when the second "p" cannot fit in the same line with the first one, it should go to the second line, which is the one below it, below the first "p". You keep trying to tell me that the two "p" don't fit into the same line, and i keep asking why doesn't it go to the 2nd line

Comment: Here is a picture illustration of what i am asking. Please take a look - > https://imgur.com/a/GOONho8

Comment: in my experience that's not how this layout works what you're talking about is the grid layout

Comment: How does it work then? how is this a grid layout, since i haven't made the blockquote display:grid?